# How to compare json with array?

Tags: bash, jq

I am looking for a way to compare data from a JSON with an Array. My JSON content looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "key": {
      "objects": [
        {
          "name": "test1",
          "some_values": "some values"
        },
        {
          "name": "test2",
          "other values": "other values"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

And I am looking for a way to filter from my JSON only the positions of object names that exist in the array

`arr=( test1 test3 )`

and then display all objects in a CSV like this:

`name,somevalue,anothervalue,etc`

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Your shown example does not contain `somevalue` or `anothervalue` or `test3`. Please add your desired exact output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: it is example of the objects, one can have name, work, address. The second name, school, salary. And for example in json I have objects with names test1,test2, and I compare with array where I have names test1,test3. I also know how to filter the output using awk, but I cannot find solution how to solve it using JQ. 
And in CSV I just plan to print all fields from object, no matter what is the key, but the number of fields will be the same.

Comment: `arr=["test1", "test3"]` is not a valid assignment in bash (try it; it'll throw an error). Do you mean `arr='["test1", "test3"]'` (assigning a bash string that corresponds to a JSON array), or `arr=( test1 test3 )` (assigning a real bash array)?

Comment: I mean array like this: arr=( test1 test3 ), thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your exact expected output (from the question it is not really clear, because the strings in the output and the input do not match), but here is a program that should give you an idea on how to get you started:

```
$ < input.json jq -r --argjson arr '["test1","test3"]' '
.[].key.objects[]
| select(.name | IN($arr[]))
| to_entries
| map(.[])
| @csv
'
"name","test1","some_values","some values"
```